# want to do aggregation based on pattern matching in unix file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i am getting below data in a file

vi file.txt

```
 "https://uat.barclaysinvestments.com/en_JE/home/funds/funds-view.html?tab=fundDocuments&isin=GB0000790005"
 "https://uat.barclaysinvestments.com/en_UK/home/funds/funds-view.html?tab=fundOverview&isin=GB0003208278"
 "https://uat.barclaysinvestments.com/en_UK/home/funds/funds-view.html?tab=fundOverview&**isin**=GB0003208278"
 "https://uat.barclaysinvestments.com/en_UK/home/funds/funds-view.html?**tab=fundPerformanc**e&isin=GB0003208278"
 "https://uat.barclaysinvestments.com/en_UK/home/funds/funds-view.html?**tab=fundPerformance**&isin=GB0003208278"
 "https://uat.barclaysinvestments.com/en_UK/home/funds/funds-view.html?tab=fundPerformance&isin=GB0003208278"
```

so by below command i am getting uniq number of isin

```
sed -n -e "/isin/ s/.*\= *//p" file.txt|sort| uniq -c |sort -nr
```

but i want to further aggregation on base of tab like overview and performance

so i will get to know  how many tab visits for particular isin.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, please use code tags for sample input and expected sample output in your posts.

Comment: `so i will get to know how many tab visits for particular isin.` This not clear. Please give one example.

Comment: If you want to count the number of tabs for a specific isin, don't use uniq as it will remove all the other occurences of your isin.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear enough, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '
{
  match($0,/Performance|Overview/);
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  if(val){
    array[val]++}
}
END{
  for(i in array){
    print i,array[i]}
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
Performance 2
Overview 2
```